# SQL Join 2 table with 2 count

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql

I'll try to explain my problem:

I've 2 similar query:

First One

```
SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD, COUNT(MOD_DESC) AS NUM
FROM MODELLI, PV_PROPOSTI, GESTIONE_COMMESSE 
WHERE  Something
```

Second one

```
SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD, COUNT(MOD_DESC) AS NUM 
FROM DISTRIB, MODELLI 
WHERE Something
```

Now, the result its' really similar since the only difference are the where conditions:

```
 MOD_DESC   MOD_COD  NUM 
 desc1      cod1     2  
 desc2      cod2     1  
 desc3      cod3     3
```

and

```
 MOD_DESC  MOD_COD  NUM 
 desc1      cod1     5  
 desc2      cod2     2  
 desc4      cod4     3
```

But now i want to "merge" the 2 queries and have a result like

```
 MOD_DESC  MOD_COD  NUM1  NUM2 
 desc1      cod1     2      5  
 desc2      cod2     1      2  
 desc3      cod3     3      0  
 desc3      cod3     0      3
```

I've tryed this query:

```
SELECT t2.MOD_DESC, t2.MOD_COD, COUNT(t2.MOD_DESC) as NUM1, COUNT(t1.MOD_DESC) as NUM2
FROM ( 

       SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD
       FROM MODELLI, PV_PROPOSTI, GESTIONE_COMMESSE 
       WHERE  something
      ) t1  

      RIGHT JOIN 
      ( 
       SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD 
       FROM DISTRIB, MODELLI 
       WHERE Something

      ) t2 ON t1.MOD_COD = t2.MOD_COD 

GROUP BY t2.MOD_DESC, t2.MOD_COD
ORDER BY t2.MOD_DESC, t2.MOD_COD
```

But i don't get the corret result.

Some help?

(i'm on oracle db)

Comment: btw you can consider to drop out that implicit joins and use explicit joins instead. At implicit joins your *something* declares both filters and join logic at explicit joins anyone can easily tell then apart

Comment: Based on the answers provided below, there seems to be a lack of clarity on what is the the primary key to the MODELLI table.  Is it MOD_COD or MOD_COD and MOD_DESC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes.

1) Do the counting in the sub-queries, not in the outer query.  Joining your results before counting will change the results of the counts.

2) Use a FULL OUTER JOIN in case there are records present in one sub-query but not the other

3) Join on BOTH fields (MOD_DESC and MOD_COD), not just one

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD, COUNT(MOD_DESC) AS NUM
  FROM MODELLI, PV_PROPOSTI, GESTIONE_COMMESSE 
  WHERE  Something
)
  AS MPG
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT MOD_DESC, MOD_COD, COUNT(MOD_DESC) AS NUM 
  FROM DISTRIB, MODELLI 
  WHERE Something
)
  AS DM
    ON  DM.MOD_DESC = MPG.MOD_DESC
    AND DM.MOD_COD  = MPG.MOD_COD
```

Comment: Thanks you. I've used the COALESCE function to have a perfect result.

Comment: No coalesce function was proposed for this solution, did you mean MauriDev?

Comment: @Patrick - He means that he took this solution *(`AGGREGATE` **then** `JOIN`)* but added `COALESCE` in the outer-most `SELECT` to cater for the `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain what kind of incorrect result you have.

But I suggest you to try something like that:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.MOD_DESC, t2.MOD_DESC) AS MOD_DESC,
       COALESCE(t1.MOD_COD, t2.MOD_COD) AS MOD_COD,
       COUNT(t2.MOD_DESC) as NUM1,
       COUNT(t1.MOD_DESC) as NUM2
  FROM ( query 1 ) AS t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
       ( query 2 ) AS t2 ON t1.MOD_COD = t2.MOD_COD
 GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.MOD_DESC, t2.MOD_DESC) AS MOD_DESC,
          COALESCE(t1.MOD_COD, t2.MOD_COD) AS MOD_COD
 ORDER BY MOD_DESC, MOD_COD
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to use FULL OUTER JOIN

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this answer?